# Linking a row within one table to another table

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

This is more of a best practice question.

I have created a table where the user will create x amount of games. Each new game is a row.
So:
Table

```
1.Game A - ROW - PK A

2.Game B - ROW - PK B
```

and so on

But each game will have x amount of players. But those players will be in a separate table.
So Game A can have 10 players, those 10 players are in a new table, called "Player Table"
But I want to link the row to its corresponding table
I was going to create each player table with the naming convention as:

```
playerTable_A

playerTable_B
```

making A and B a PK, then using that to query the right table.
Is there a better way to do this?
Hope I explained it well enough

Comment: Have you consider using the PK as a foreign key in a single player table?

Comment: I thought my method may be easier, because if the user wanted to deleted a game, then all I had to do was drop the table.

Comment: @CashLo having tried to work this out, I think our way is the best way to do this. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I understand completely, but if I do, you have a games table which contains one row per game, and a players table, with one row per player. If you want to connect them, all you have to do is create a user_game_association table which will look like: 
PlayerID, GameID

So if you want to connect player 7 to game 10, you just insert to this new table the values 7, 10.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You want a *junction*/*association* table.  It would look something like:

```
create table gamePlayers (
    gameId int references games(gameId),
    playerId int references players(playerId)
);
```